# Multithread Microsoft docs code example doesn't return the same output on my machines

Tags: c#, multithreading

I tried to run the example presented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=net-7.0) in the "Examples" section from MS docs, but the output is not the same pointed out by the document.

This is my output.

```
Main thread: Start a second thread.
Main thread: Do some work.
Main thread: Do some work.
Main thread: Do some work.
Main thread: Do some work.
Main thread: Call Join(), to wait until ThreadProc ends.
ThreadProc: 0
ThreadProc: 1
ThreadProc: 2
ThreadProc: 3
ThreadProc: 4
ThreadProc: 5
ThreadProc: 6
ThreadProc: 7
ThreadProc: 8
ThreadProc: 9
Main thread: ThreadProc.Join has returned.  Press Enter to end program.
```

Comparing this output with the one given by MS you can see the outputs of the two threads are not twisted as in MS docs.
At first sight I supposed that was a CPU concern, because I executed it on a M1 Apple chip, but after I tried on a x64 Intel hexacore, and the result is the same, I can't understand why the two thread outputs are not twisted.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multithreaded code have inherently indeterministic ordering unless specifically synchronized. The example is likely very old and written with a single core CPU in mind. On any modern CPU you will likely always have some CPU core available, so yielding have little effect.

If you run something else that consumes 100% CPU you should force the scheduler to actually switch between threads whenever one yields, and you will likely see some other ordering.

I would not recommend using that example for anything, modern code should in most cases prefer using  `Task` over `Thread`.

Comment: Thank you for your clear reply. You are absolutely right about  `Task` class in everyday usage, and I'm focusing on Task-based asynchronous pattern than threads, but in my opinion a fly-by on threads should be done, at least for knowledge purposes only. Anyway, yes,  Task and Parallel library must be preferred over threads.